# What is the recommended way to serialize django data to json to work with jqgrid?

Tags: django, json, jqgrid, django-views

I've been spending my evening fighting with getting jsonReader: set up correctly in jqgrid to match the JSON output of django's serializer capabilities.  I have since gotten sick of trying and decided I should just make a view to give the output jqgrid wants json to be in by default.  My plan is to write a view that forms a string that looks like jqgrid wants it.  This seems a bit ugly to me (ie lots of manual formatting of JSON), but I think this is probably the most expandable route for the future should I choose to use more functionality of jqgrid.  What is the recommended way of getting custom formatted JSON out of Django?  What is the recommended Django way of accomplishing what I will accomplish by creating a view like the below example?

```
def serializedData(request):
    querySet = Model.objects.filter(date=None).order_by('id')
    data = '{'
    for row in querySet:
        # go through each item and make a pretty json row and add it to data
    data += '}'
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a django template that matched the json format I wanted.  This turned out to be a couple of lines so I can't imagine making it any simpler, especially when the names have to be manually assigned anyway.

example..something similar to this:

```
[{% for herp in derps %}
    { "id":"{{ herp.id }}___", "value":"{{ herp.value }}"}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm already able to use that if I choose, I was just looking for something to streamline the jqgrid json formatting for me (ie the steps creating that "data" variable).  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check out some of the serialization/API frameworks available out there :

- [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/overview), which I don't like so much since the serialization is not so flexible in my opinion.
- [SpitEat](http://bitbucket.org/sebpiq/spiteat), which is built for allowing very flexible serialization, however the doc is completely outdated ... I don't find the time to fix it... but you can probably find your way by reading the tests, and the source code (which is completely documented and doc is up-to-date)
- more packages [there](http://djangoplugables.com/grids/g/api/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I think I may just go my own manual route, but do so cautiously while keeping an eye on what is available.  Going the manual route will make me less susceptible to 3rd part framework changes.

Comment: That's also a choice ! But if you finally need to serialize a lot of different things, and your need grows along the development, you might end-up writing a lot of code that you could have avoided by using one of those frameworks ! And what you took for a gain of time (taking your own way), might end-up in a big waste of time !!!